# How can I effectively store associated records in cloud firestore?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have a group chat feature in my firestore app. So, I have a messages collection that looks something like this...

```
{
   text: 'Hi there. This is a message.',
   createdAt: '8/7/2018 3:28:20 PM',
   author: 'GKN1q0Y1D3adLNf4xw84tOzukA22'
}
```

In the example above, I simply store the user id in the author field. However, it isn't really feasible to fetch the entire user record for each message. So, I switched to something like this...

```
{
   text: 'Hi there. This is a message.',
   createdAt: '8/7/2018 3:28:20 PM',
   author: {
       id: 'GKN1q0Y1D3adLNf4xw84tOzukA22'
       name: 'Charlie',
       avatarURL: 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...'
   }
}
```

Now, I can display the name of the author and show their avatar with a single query to the messages collection. This is great, but what happens when a user changes their avatar? Or their name?

Do I just write a cloud function to update every message sent by this person, knowing that a single person could potentially send thousands of messages? Is it reasonable to make potentially thousands of writes in a single cloud function invocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a requirement that all messages must be shown with the most up to date avatar, all the time, for all time, then you probably don't want to duplicate that data across all those messages.  When the number of messages for a user gets very large, and they want to change their avatar, you'll need to querying for ALL of those messages and update ALL of them, which can be costly.

Instead, you probably want to store the avatar keyed by their user name, and require the client to fetch that document to get updates as they occur.  With the assumption that the client caches the document until it changes, you will incur very few extra reads this way.

Bottom line is that you'll have to compare the costs of each implementation and make a decision based on your speed/size/cost constraints.  You can't get the best of all three all the time.

Comment: That was fast. I love this website. The avatar solution you described works well, but the name is still an issue. "If you have a requirement that all messages must be shown with the most up to date avatar, all the time, for all time, then you probably don't want to duplicate that data across all those messages." I think I'm just going to relax that requirement. Just wanted to make sure there wasn't some alternate solution that I was missing. Thanks.